# How can I save my python output to text file

Tags: python

I have to save my results to txt file but no idea for this. I greatly need some of you can help me. I really appreciate. 
My code :

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import glob

filenames = glob.glob('E:\koppen-master\dat_Viet\T2m_*.txt')

for g in filenames:

    print("#",g)


    data1=np.loadtxt(fname=g,comments="#")
    nyr1=len(data1[:,1])/31 

    nyr1=int(nyr1)

    r3T2m=np.reshape(data1[:,1:13],(nyr1,31,12))

    r2T2m_mn=np.zeros(shape=(nyr1,12))

    iyr1=0    

    while iyr1 < nyr1:

            imn1=0  

            while imn1<12:

                    idy1=0  

                    ndy1=0  

                    while idy1 <31:

                            if r3T2m[iyr1][idy1][imn1]>=-10.: 

                                    ndy1=ndy1+1

                                    r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]=r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]+r3T2m[iyr1][idy1][imn1]

                            idy1=idy1+1

                    r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]=round(r2T2m_mn[iyr1][imn1]/float(ndy1),2)

                    imn1=imn1+1

            print ("#",iyr1+1998,"  ",r2T2m_mn[iyr1])

            iyr1=iyr1+1
```

My result like this :

[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try using open() method? If not you can study from here: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp  and then you can append or directly write into your file. Just open this link you will come to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the [python file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html), see section 'Reading and Writing Files' for more information.
Just above your for, include that line:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    try:
        #put your for and while loops here
```

Right after your print statement include this line (same indentation level):

```
f.write('#{} {}\n'.format(int(iyr1)+1998, r2T2m_mn[iyr1]))
```

At the end of the file just put (indentation level from `try` statement):

```
except Exception as err:
    print('There was an error. Detail: {}'.format(err))
finally:
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code above your for loop as shown below :

```
f = open("results.txt", "w")
for g in filenames:
```

Add this line of code after your print statement as shown below :

```
print ("#",iyr1+1998,"  ",r2T2m_mn[iyr1])    
f.write("#" + (iyr1+1998) + "  " + r2T2m_mn[iyr1] + "\n")
```

Add this line at the end of your code (outside all loops) :

```
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried to run and It showed that :  f.write("#",iyr1+1998,"  ",r2T2m_mn[iyr1],"\n")
TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (5 given)

Comment: I got the solution. Thank you for your time